# Existence of a field with $p^2$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$=$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ where $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ is prime

I need to show there is a field with $p^2$ elements.

I am not sure where to start with this.

Comment: Show that there is an irreducible quadratic polynomial over your field.

Answer (score 3):

If $p=2$, consider $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/{(x^2+x+1)}$. If $p$ is odd, there is $b\in\mathbb{F}_p$ such that $b^2-1$ is a quadratic non-residue - if all the quadratic non-residues were followed by a quadratic non-residue, $0$ would be a quadratic non-residue, contradiction. Hence $x^2-2bx+1$ is an irreducible quadratic polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_p$, and $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2-2bx+1)$ is a field with $p^2$ elements.

Comment: (It is probably better to avoid the language of quadratic residues in this context, no?)

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, a little more advanced than the basic one in Jack's answer: take the polynomial $\;x^{p^2}-x\in\Bbb F_p[x]\;$ and let $\;K\;$ be its splitting field over $\;\Bbb F_p\;$.

Now just prove that $\;\left|K\right|=\left|\Bbb F_{p^2}\right|=p^2\;$ and we're done by the uniqueness of finite fields.

Comment: Notice that the point is to prove the existence of a field with $p^2$ elements so we cannot prove in the middle that «$|K|=|\mathbb F_{p^2}$»! :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, that's precisely what the above is proving: by means of splitting fields to get a field with exactly $\;p^2\;$ elements. That is not "in the middle": that's the proof! If you want you may take away that "middle" $\;\Bbb F_{p^2}\;$ ...

Comment: You cannot refer to $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ is you do not know that there exist fields with $p^2$ elements! And you don't, because the whole point of this question is to prove that they do exist! (You seem to have understood a different question by the way as evinced by your «and we are done by the uniqueness of finite fields»)

Comment: Common, @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: it's just a way to call that group $\;K\;$ whose construction is hinted in the above answer, and it's just a way to hint that it actually is the field we're looking for. It never matters, though: whoever doesn't like it erase that $\;\Bbb F_{p^2}\;$ in that last line.

Comment: Ok,if you do not care about making sense (or answering the question asked by the OP) I don't mind!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, I see you're utterly unable to understand what I meant. Oh, well.

Comment: I understand what you **meant**: I am suggesting you changee what you **wrote** so that it matches that.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

suppose $p\neq 2$ and consider $\eta : \mathbb{F}_p^*\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p^*$ defined as $\eta(x)=x^2$

- Prove that $\eta$ is not injective (This does not behave properly in $p=2$ case)
- Thus, $\eta$ is not surjective (Why ??)
- So, you can find some $a\in \mathbb{F}_p^*$ that is not a square. (Why ??)
- Consider $\mathbb{F}_p[\sqrt{a}]=\{m+n\sqrt{a}  : m,n \in \mathbb{F}_p\}$ (Is this a field?)
- What is the cardinality of $\mathbb{F}_p[\sqrt{a}]$?

It is your turn to construct field of order $4$ (you may even get some answers in this same site).

Another way of looking at the general case is...

**You can surely say there does exists an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ of degree $2$**

Just check no of polynomials of degree $2$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ and look for all possible combinations like $(x-a)(x-b)$ (be careful in counting)

so, you would know that there does exist some irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ and consider $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f(x))$